# Compute the volume of a cube not axis-aligned

Tags: geometry, 3d, volume

I have objects in 3D which have 8 corners and most of the time they look like cubes. I need to compute the volume of those objects. Since they are not axis-aligned I can't use the standard formula $V = l^3$.

Are there other solutions?

---

Example image
[image]

Comment: "Since they are not axis-aligned I can't use the standard formula": why not ???

Comment: What is a volume that "most of the time looks like a cube" ?

Comment: Check the distance between corners and the orthogonality of the edges.

Comment: This is an example image to better understand what I mean

Comment: I feel certain we can tell you how to compute the volumes if you can describe the solids fully.  Are the edge lengths always the same?  Are the edges perpendicular to one another?  Are opposite faces parallel, etc?

Comment: No, the edges aren't of the same length and not perpendicular. I just have the x,y,z of the 8 corners.

Comment: Please add this info to your question. A concrete example would also be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide your cuboid into tetrahedra, compute the volume of each tetrahedron and add them.

The volume of a tetrahedron with vertices $OPQR$ is given by:
$$
V={1\over6}|(P-O)\cdot(Q-O)\times(R-O)|.
$$

A possible decomposition is shown below: a cuboid with opposite faces $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ is the sum of five tetrahedra $ABCF$, $ACDH$, $AFEH$, $CFGH$, $ACFH$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand exactly what you mean, but it seems you can calculate the lengths of the sides of the cube by applying the formula for norm of vectors, i.e. length equals $\sqrt{(x_1-x_o)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 + (z_1 - z_2)^2}$ and then applying the formula for a cube.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the body is a [Parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelepiped), generated by the vectors $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$, the volume is the absolute value of the triple product
$$(\vec a\times\vec b)\cdot\vec c$$
(that also can be calculated as the determinant of the matrix formed by the column vectors $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c$).